is 3-SAT ∈ NTIME(n^3)?
I'm struggling to understand the time complexity of 3-SAT using a non-deterministic Turing machine, as well as the relationship between NTIME and DTIME
For example, let's say we have 2 literals. My intuition is this:

We have 4 literals to choose from, as each literal can also be a negation
We have 4^3 ((2n)^3) potential clauses (different permutations of 3 of them, with repetition).

An NTM could run 4 combinations of the 2 literals simultaneously, and so the time complexity would be O(n^3), where n is the number of literals. Is this true?
If we now want to use a DTM instead, we would have to run combinations of the two literals sequentially, so the time complexity would be O(n^3 * 2^n) or O(2^n).
I'm new to the topic and I feel like I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something, as I can't find any information online confirming/denying this. Could anyone please help me out? How do I describe 3-SAT in NTIME/DTIME?

I am not sure what you meant by permutations (the clauses are part of the input formula). So I will formulate the problem more precisely:
Let $\varphi = C_1 \wedge C_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge C_m$ be a $\text{3SAT}$ formula over the variable set $X = \{ x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n\}$. So we have $m$ clauses and $n$ variables (in particular, $2n$ literals). The runtime is defined w.r.t to the input's length $|\langle \varphi \rangle|$, where $\langle \varphi \rangle$ is an encoding of $\varphi$.
Note that the formula $\varphi$ is satisfiable iff there exists an assignment $f: X \to \{ F, T\}$ that satisfies every clause of $\varphi$. Also note that an NTM $M$ that decides $\text{3SAT}$ accepts $\varphi$ iff there exists an accepting run of $M$ on $\varphi$. The crux of the idea here is that nondeterminism helps in terms of runtime because we need to check an existential property and the semantics of NTMs are existential. So the advantage of using nondeterminism would come from the fact that the NTM $M$ can guess a satisfying assignment $f$, and need not to iterate over all possible assignments. Specifically, $M$ operates as follows:
1- For $i\in [n]$, $M$ guesses whether we assign to $x_i$ $T$ or $F$. This takes in total $O(n)$ steps.
2- $M$ evaluates $\varphi$ under the guessed assignment $f$. This is simply done by checking whether for every clause, there is a literal that appears in that clause and evaluates to $T$ under $f$. This takes $O(m\cdot n)$ steps.
Note that $m, n \leq |\langle \varphi \rangle|$. Can you analyze the runtime of $M$ as a function of the input's length $|\langle \varphi \rangle|$?
Now using a DTM, we don't know yet if we have something that is notably more clever to do other than iterating over all possible assignments. In fact, it is an open problem whether there is a DTM that can decide the satisfiability of $\varphi$ in time polynomial in $|\langle \varphi \rangle|$. The latter is known as the $\text{P}$ vs $\text{NP}$ problem, which is one of the fundamental open questions in complexity theory. In particular, it is not known yet whether $\text{3SAT}$ is in $\text{DTIME($n^k$)}$ for any $k$ ($n$ here stands for the input's length).

Thanks for the answer. I suppose my question is, wouldn't $m$ have a direct relationship to $n$? For example, suppose $n=1$ and our literal is $x$. Then wouldn't there be 8 possible clauses? $x \lor x \lor \neg x$,  $x \lor \neg x \lor \neg x$, etc. until we have 8 or $(2n)^3$ combinations? I feel like this is where my misunderstanding stems from. Could there be repeating clauses?

The runtime is defined as a function of $|\langle \varphi \rangle|$ (which is larger than the number of variables) and not a function of the number of variables (although the relation between |⟨⟩| and the number of variables can be assumed to be polynomial as you've shown, but that comes at the cost of removing duplicate clauses which can be huge). So the $n$ inside the expression $NTIME(n^3)$ is not the number of variables, it is the input's length $|\langle \varphi \rangle|$.

To be more specific, you can have $\varphi = (x\lor x \lor x) \wedge \cdots \wedge (x\lor x \lor x) \wedge \cdots $ where we repeat the same clause, $(x\lor x \lor x)$,  $2^n$ times, where $n$ is the number of variables. In this case, the runtime cannot be polynomial in $n$ , yet is polynomial in $|\langle \varphi\rangle|$ .

I think this explains it, I didn't consider there could be duplicate clauses. Thanks a bunch!

You're welcome!
